# Mysql exclude rows by values in other rows (get the leaves of a tree)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mariadb

I have this table:

```
+------------+-------------+------------------+
| product_id | category_id |  parent_category |
+------------+-------------+------------------+
|          1 |         aaa |                0 |
|          1 |         bbb |              aaa |
|          1 |         ccc |              bbb |
|          2 |         aaa |                0 |
|          2 |         bbb |              aaa |
|          2 |         ddd |                0 |
```

So I want to exclude parent categories within same `product_id` to get only lowest level categories from the table. `parent_category` `0` means it's top level category (has no parents)

For example, first row with `category` `aaa` is excluded because in a second row there's a category `bbb` and `aaa` is parent for `bbb` (for product_id=1).

Desired output:

```
+------------+---------------+
| product_id |   category_id |
+------------+---------------+
|          1 |           ccc |          
|          2 |           bbb |           
|          2 |           ddd |
```

So practically category stucture like `aaa->bbb->ccc` and `ddd->eee->fff`.
And if product in `aaa` `bbb` `ddd` categories I want to get `bbb` and `ddd`.

My thoughts: php is in use so I'd make dirty php loops.

Edit: to clarify it's a problem to get the leaves of a tree

Comment: how do you make sure that your data is sorted like you said?

Comment: sorting doesn't matter. that's simplified example

Comment: You can use `CURSOR` for your problem! Read this post which is somehow same problem : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63134369/mysql-user-variable-assignement-with-count/63137336#63137336.

Comment: can you elaborate you question more clearly.

Comment: I tried realy hard. I want to get lowest level product categories (see second table). There are can be multiple categories for product.
Or I want to exclude parent ones that present. Parents are added automatically when I import products.

Comment: okay got it, are they sequence? mean is 1st product category is always 0 and last category is ddd?

Comment: yes, 0 means category is 1st level. no, ddd is also first in this example. 
category stucture like aaa->bbb->ccc and ddd->eee->fff
ddd is parent for eee bot not for aaa, bbb or ccc

Comment: that's default opencart tables. category and product_to_category.

Comment: is parent category is fixed? or is there any other way to differentiate `parent_category` type ?

Comment: yes, there are `category` table so category structure is fixed. `aaa` is always parent for `bbb`. `bbb` is always parent for `ccc`. 
the table I specify is "select * from category join product_to_category using(category_id)"

Comment: @Hebe updated the answer. Hope it will work for you

Comment: thanks, I'll take time to investigate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So when i get this right you want to get the leaves of a tree. In case you are not strictly tied to the `recursive CTE` you can simply check if a given category has children. If not - its a leaf (respecting the same product_id).

```
SELECT product_id, category_id
FROM categories c
WHERE
    (
        SELECT
            count(*)
        FROM
            categories c2
        WHERE
            c2.parent_category = c.category_id
            AND c2.product_id = c.product_id
    ) = 0
```

Working [example](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/g4wmr4hPL1Tjp7zBieE3oc/1).

In case you want to check the `product_id` of every parent this won't work though.

Comment: excellent! works exactly correct. I didn't get the case it wouldn't work though.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `recursive CTE`:

```
with recursive cte as (
      select 
        *, 0 as level, concat(product_id, '-', category_id) as ar 
      from 
        samp 
      where 
        parent_category ='0'
union all
      select 
        t1.*, t2.level+1, ar
      from samp t1 
        inner join 
           cte t2 
        on t1.parent_category =t2.category_id and t1.product_id=t2.product_id
),
cte1 as (
      select 
        *, row_number() over (partition by ar order by level desc) as rank_ 
      from 
        cte 
         )

    select 
        product_id, category_id, parent_category 
    from 
        cte1 
    where 
        rank_=1
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=5eebf5890c66b1b63b012a738916472f)

Comment: thanks for sharing, but recursive CTE is hard to comprehend so I'll accept other answer