# How to row_number() a ranked dataset in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

```
a   b       c   D
X   201801  1   1
X   201802  0   1
X   201803  0   2
X   201804  1   1
X   201805  0   1
Y   201801  1   1
Y   201802  0   1
Y   201803  0   2
Y   201804  1   1
Y   201805  0   1
```

Here are 3 columns in my dataset (a,b,c). How can I add a new column D in MySQL?
D is ordered by c, add 1 if current c and previous c have the same value, otherwise, start from 1.

Comment: Please add sample data as text to the question..

Comment: What is your version of MySql?

Comment: I'm running Mysql 8.0

Comment: have the same value? which values? c and d in the previous row? or current c and previous c?

Comment: current c and previous c

Comment: You can do it by cursor inside a SP. see https://stackoverflow.com/a/63137336/2527458

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a gaps-and-islands problem, where you want to build groups of adjacent records having the same value.

Here, the simplest approach is probably to use the difference between row numbers to define the groups:

```
select a, b, c, 
    row_number() over(partition by a, c, rn1 - rn2 order by b) d
from (
    select t.*,
        row_number() over(partition by a order by b) rn1,
        row_number() over(partition by a, c order by b) rn2
    from mytable t
) t
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f5432add2cb376a712f182108ed586dc)**:

```
a  |      b | c  |  d
:- | -----: | :- | -:
X  | 201801 | 1  |  1
X  | 201802 | 0  |  1
X  | 201803 | 0  |  2
X  | 201804 | 1  |  1
X  | 201805 | 0  |  1
Y  | 201801 | 1  |  1
Y  | 201802 | 0  |  1
Y  | 201803 | 0  |  2
Y  | 201804 | 1  |  1
Y  | 201805 | 0  |  1
```

Comment: try to run `select t.* from mytable t` in the demo! Why has the same result?

Answer (score 0):

I would define the groups just using a cumulative sum of `c` and then using `row_number()`:

```
select t.*,
       row_number() over (partition by a, grp, c order by b) as d
from (select t.*,
             sum(c) over (partition by a order by b) as grp
      from t
     ) t;
```

This seems like the simplest solution.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3b2ac83baef9df025ba7de702d212521) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: @PcWang . . . I know.  I offered it because it is a simpler solution.